# Is there is a proof that the events of occurring of twin primes are independent?

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The motivation to this question can be found in: http://curvebank.calstatela.edu/prime/prime.htm

I am interested on the meaning of the second paragraph:

Until recently, it had been conjectured that there are infinitely many twin primes. If the **probability** of a random integer  $n$  and the integer  $n+2$  being prime were **statistically independent events**, then it would follow from the prime number theorem that there are about $(n/((ln n)²))$ twin primes less than or equal to $n$. **These probabilities are not independent**.

I have two **questions**:

1) How explain the contradiction in saying that: **if** the events are independent then there are about $(n/((ln n)²))$ twin primes less than or equal to $n$ followed by the last sentence which is the negation of the first.

2) Is there is a proof that the events of occurring of twin primes are independent

Comment: Not sure why it says "it *had* been conjectured".  The twin primes conjecture is still widely believed and still open (but the state-of-the-art since 2013 is much closer than I would have thought possible).

Comment: @ErickWong: This is an old webpage.

Comment: $-1$ because this question is answered on the very web page you linked to.

Comment: @WillO: I am not undertood the meaning of that paragraph.

Comment: @DER Need I say that the twin primes conjecture was also still a conjecture back when the page was written?

Comment: @ErickWong: No. I am not undertood the meaning of that paragraph

Comment: Talking about independence is a little difficult to make meaningful, since prime numbers are not random events.  On top of that, there is some empirical evidence that twin primes are slightly more common than $\frac{n}{(\ln n)^2}$, perhaps about $30\%$ more for quite large $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is no contradiction in there, it's just the way logical implication works: if you say something of sort "if it rained in the morning, the roads are wet" and then you claim that it did *not* rain in the morning, both claims can hold true. Same thing happens here. Generally, if you have a statement "$A$ implies $B$" and $A$ is false, then the implication is true.

2) "Probability" that number $n=3k+1$ is prime is approximately $\ln n$, but the same "probability" for $n+2=3k+3$ is equal to 0, because $3\mid n+2$.

Comment: @DER Read the answer.  2) is a proof that the probabilities are _not_ independent.  Why do you still need to ask if there is a proof that they are?

Comment: @ErickWong: To see the different consequences of that fact.

Comment: @DER You just asked for a proof that they are not independent and I gave you one.

Comment: @Wojowu:  Your "proof" in (2) is not responsive to the question.  If one of two events has probability zero, then the probabilities of the two events *are* independent.

Comment: @WillO: Yes, the answer contradict this link: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/07/ams-lecture-structure-and-randomness-in-the-prime-numbers/

Comment: @WillO Yes, I see why this is wrong now.

Comment: @DER How does my answer contradict what's on the linked page?

Comment: @Wojowu: It stated that the events are independent: In the section: **Random models for the primes**.

Comment: @DER I don't see anywhere stated that the events are independent.

Comment: @Wojowu: See: Random models for the primes. Item 3

Comment: @DER The author only says "Assuming these two events are independent...". He never explicitly claims that they *are* independent, he only speculates what happens under such assumption.

Comment: @Wojowu: So it is impossible to claim the nature of this dependence or indepenence.

Comment: @DER:  Maybe you should take a moment or two to read one of the pages you keep linking to, rather than ask other people to read them to you.